# Best practice for defining a Java variable that acts (something) like a C's local static variable

Tags: java

In C, I can create a static variable in a function. The space for that variable is not allocated along with the function variables, it's allocated at program startup time. (Don't mock my C too harshly, I've been programming in Java for way too long :)

```
void myFunc(){
  static SomeStruct someStruct;
  someStruct.state=INITIALIZED;
  goDoSomethingInteresting(MY_COMMAND,&someStruct);
}
```

In Java, if I want to do something similar, I create a class variable and then use it.

```
Class TheClass {
   SomeStruct someStruct = new SomeStruct();
   void myFunc(){
     someStruct.setState(INITIALIZED);
     goDoSomethingInteresting(MY_COMMAND,someStruct);
   }
}
```

My question is what is the best practice for doing something like this? I'd really like to associate my variable `someStruct` with my function `myFunc`, because `myFunc` is the only code that should know about or use `someStruct`, but there's no way to make that association except to put the variable close to the function in code. If you put it above, then the Javadoc for the function looks wonky, if you put it below, then it's not very clear that they belong together.

Normally I would just create `someStruct` locally, but in my case it's very expensive to create `someStruct`, and I call `myFunc` in a tight loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small class will associate `someStruct` with the behavior of `myFunc` cleanly, but it's extra overhead for understanding and maintaining things.  Might be worthwhile, might not be.

```
class TheClass {
   MyFuncBehavior myFuncer = new MyFuncBehavior();
   void myFunc() {
      myFuncer.myFunc();
   }
}

class MyFuncBehavior {
   private static SomeStruct someStruct = new SomeStruct();

   public void myFunc() {
     someStruct.setState(INITIALIZED);
     goDoSomethingInteresting(MY_COMMAND,someStruct);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most Java-like option, although still slightly confusing and harder to maintain.

Comment: I agree with @biziclop. This is the only way to do what I ask -- but I'll probably never do it unless I have a lot of `someStruct` like variables. Note that this could be the case in a Java game where you don't want to create lots of work for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are writing the java class, just make it a private member of your class. Put a comment next to it if you want to stop other people who might be working on that same file from using it elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 2):

In C a `function static variable`

- has the life of the program
- has the scope of the function

That is, once initialized it has available on every call to the function with the last value assigned to it but is not accessible outside the function.

This will fit nicely if you convert the function into a class with one method and make the static variable a member of that class.

e.g.

```
void F()
{
   static int i;
}
```

Becomes

```
class F
{
    int i;
    func() ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much point trying to enforce encapsulation within a single source file (i.e. a class and all its inner classes) and Java seems to follow this principle.

Anyone with access to the source code can change it to have access to any field.

However redesigning your code is an option:

1. You can extract `myFunc()` into a separate class along with the field it uses.
2. You can simply change the method's signature to `void myFunc( SomeStruct struct)` and pass it as a parameter. Store it as a local variable of the caller.

If the loop is indeed very tight, the overhead will be minimal. (Personally I wouldn't do any of the above.)

Comment: You're right as far as encapsulation within the class goes, but I'm looking for a way to make it clear that `someStruct` is only to be used within `myFunc`. In C this is clear because it's not visible anyplace else. In Java it's not clear unless I write a comment that says as much.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada But that's exactly the point: the main unit of encapsulation in Java is the class. Trying to shoehorn C concepts into it is going to end in tears.

Comment: Not at all -- I can imagine a new Java idiom -- the static local. Imagine `public void myFunc(){ static SomeStruct ss = new SomeStruct(); godo(CMD,ss); }`. In my imaginary world, `ss` is now just what I want -- it gets allocated along with the class level variables, but is only visible within `myFunc`.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada Imagination is all well but what would be the point? What would you hope to gain? Who do you want to hide it from? Other developers? What's to stop them moving it into a regular field? Also, how would it work in a polymorphic environment? What if you override that method? What if you override the method and then call the `super` version? What if the method has a type parameter? You're just asking for trouble.

Comment: The whole idea is wrapped up in [InformationHiding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InformationHiding). `someStruct` should only be useful in `myFunc` so only `myFunc` should know about it. There's no simple way of doing this in Java, that's all. So what if you override the method -- the new method doesn't have to know or have access to what the old method does.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada Whether you agree with it or not, information hiding only works on a class level in Java. Therefore you have to design your classes in a way that enforces correct information hiding. Static local variables in C were a necessary evil rather than good programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

> In Java, if I want to do something similar, I create a class variable and then use it.

Yes it is the best practice.

Comment: What I'd really like is a way to "hide" `someStruct` from the rest of the class in which it lives.

Comment: but why a local variable is not enough?

Comment: Because `new SomeStruct()` can take a loooong time.

Comment: if you want to hide the variable that a methods use to other object methods it means that you need to split your objects in two, and then incapsulate one object in the other